# Access denied for user `staging`@`%`

Tags: mysql, import

I am importing a sql file to database using command prompt.But getting an error of `Access denied`. Details:

- user: staging
- host : %

It works with the following details:

- user : staginguser
- host: localhost

**Import command:** 
`mysql -u staging -p dbname < filename.sql`

Can anyone tell me how to import a file for user with host `%` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, and only for clarity purposes, you may wish to put the dbname just after the MySQL command. Second, you may wish to check if the contents of the file has references to the source database name (something like .) and the old db name differs from the new. Third, check that user staging has access to the db and if yes, check that it has the required permissions to perform whatever is contained in the file.

After you have done all the above, post an update to your question with all the details.

By the way, if you are using `%` as the host, it means that the user must have access from any host. Does he/she?

Comment: yes user has access plus i have granted all the permissions as well.

Comment: From the terminal issue the command `SELECT User FROM mysql.user;` and see if the user you are using is shown (I mean if you are using `staging@%` there must be such user in the list).

Comment: You should look for a user `staging@%` and not `staging`. A user is defined along with the host, so `staging@%` and `staging@localhost` are, in fact, two different users in the sense of access/permissions.

Comment: When i logged in with `root` user, the query worked but when I tried logging with `staging` user then `ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'` . And the user `staging` showed up in the list . In my case, it isn't defined with host name. I fetched the `host` separately

Comment: Where is your DB installed? In your localhost?

Comment: yes! oh my god, will this only work on server? I am new to this so please bare :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118912/discussion-between-fdavidov-and-lisa).